# incremento diario en series de pandas

Tags: python, pandas

si tengo un df con una fecha y valores para cada dia como puedo hacer el incremento diario de esa variable?

```
serie

fecha
2020-03-13       3
2020-03-14       5
2020-03-15       9
2020-03-16      12
2020-03-17      21
2020-03-18      29
```

he hecho

```
serie1 = serie.reset_index()

for e in serie1.col2:

    print(serie1[e] - serie1[e-1])
```

me devuelve 5 numeros y me salta este error:

```
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

una vez conseguido, como se puede saber la fecha en la que empieza a descender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes una Serie o lo aplicas sobre una columna, asumiendo que está correctamente ordenada en base a la fecha, lo que buscas ya existe en Pandas, es [`pandas.Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff):

```
import pandas as pd

serie = pd.Series(
    [3,  5,  9, 12, 21, 29], 
    name="fecha", 
    index=["2020-03-13", "2020-03-14", "2020-03-15",
           "2020-03-16", "2020-03-17", "2020-03-18"]
    )
```

> ```
> >>> serie.diff()
>
> 2020-03-13    NaN
> 2020-03-14    2.0
> 2020-03-15    4.0
> 2020-03-16    3.0
> 2020-03-17    9.0
> 2020-03-18    8.0
> Name: fecha, dtype: float64
> ```

En el caso de aplicarlo sobre la columna de un DataFrame es lo mismo:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "fallecimientos": [3,  5,  9, 12, 21, 29], 
    "fecha": ["2020-03-13", "2020-03-14", "2020-03-15",
              "2020-03-16", "2020-03-17", "2020-03-18"]}, 
    ).set_index("fecha")
```

> ```
> >>> df
>             fallecimientos
> fecha                     
> 2020-03-13               3
> 2020-03-14               5
> 2020-03-15               9
> 2020-03-16              12
> 2020-03-17              21
> 2020-03-18              29
> ```

---

> ```
> >>> df.fallecimientos.diff()
> fecha
> 2020-03-13    NaN
> 2020-03-14    2.0
> 2020-03-15    4.0
> 2020-03-16    3.0
> 2020-03-17    9.0
> 2020-03-18    8.0
> Name: fallecimientos, dtype: float64
> ```